# Button is not working with Update Panel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, web

I have placed a timer and a label for displaying countdown time in an update panel. I have placed the next button for displaying the next question outside the update panel.

My problem is that the button click is not working with the update panel. Without using the update panel and the timer it works well. How can I solve the problem?

I have also tried to place whole tools inside the update panel. It didn't help me.

*Here is my code:*

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
         </ContentTemplate>
                 </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style2">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblOptions" runat="server">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style2">
                <table class="style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style2">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" onclick="btnNext_Click" Text="Next"
                                    Width="75px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" onclick="btnFinish_Click"
                                Text="Finish" Width="75px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style2">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="lblScore" runat="server">Score : </asp:Label>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I added the following code.

```
<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNext" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers>
```

Still it didn't work. Could you please help me....

The selection of radio button is automatically cleared when using update panel. Any help....?

Thank you....

Comment: What do you mean with "not working", does it cause any postback at all?

Comment: is there any exception or error you are getting??

Comment: Have you just tried to add AutoPostBack = "true" to your controller "<asp:button/>" ?

Comment: selection of radio button might be getting cleaned due to timer tick event. try and add AsyncPostBackTrigger for time tick event also or keep timer in separate updatepanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using master page , then add this code in you're page load event

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;
```

```
ToolkitScriptManager objScriptManager = (ToolkitScriptManager)this.Master.FindControl("ScriptManager1");
    objScriptManager.AsyncPostBackTimeout = 36000;
```

..............

Comment: thank you I got it by adding `using AjaxControlToolkit;` in my page load event.

Answer (score 7):

Your UpdatePanel is malformed. You have one extra **asp:UpdatePanel** tag in the markup.

Use this instead:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
                    </asp:Timer>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style3">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style2">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblOptions" runat="server">
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style2">
                    <table class="style1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" onclick="btnNext_Click" Text="Next" Width="75px" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" onclick="btnFinish_Click" Text="Finish" Width="75px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblScore" runat="server">Score : </asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems that are unmatched tags. Once correct and go through the layout once again. Instead of using AjaxToolkit library, run with jquery navigation plugins, you can feel more better.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<Triggers>    
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNext" />
        </Triggers>
```

and add Ajaxtoolkit to your project... then just give below link after <%@ Page .........%>

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

also add following code in your form tag.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You must put the Button in update pannel then it will work fine

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
                    </asp:Timer>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style3">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style2">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblOptions" runat="server">
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="margin-left: 40px" class="style2">
                    <table class="style1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" onclick="btnNext_Click" Text="Next"
                                        Width="75px" />
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" onclick="btnFinish_Click"
                                    Text="Finish" Width="75px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style2">
                                &nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="lblScore" runat="server">Score : </asp:Label>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</ContentTemplate>
                     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register NEXT button to update panel. for registration you need to use `<asp:asyncpostbacktrigger xmlns:asp="#unknown">` inside the UpdatePanel

i.e.

```
<updatepanel>
   <contenttemplate>
       ... body ......
   </contenttemplate>

  <triggers>
     <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="btnNext" eventname="Click" />
  </triggers>
<updatepanel></updatepanel></updatepanel>
```

Comment: registering the NEXT button to update panel also helps me work out with my problem. you have my +100.

Answer (score 0):

If in the page there are validation error (include hidden errors es: modal dialog).
Event click not work.
Tray to set a different validation group to the button (es: validationGroup="xxx")

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFinish" validationGroup="none" runat="server" onclick="btnFinish_Click" Text="Finish" />
```

Hope this help.