# Button not working in Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I know it has been asked before, but I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

aspx (no master page, this is a part of the page):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />

<AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">    </AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" Visible="False">


            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="Article">
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Download Excel" OnClick="btnExcel_Click" />

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="RESET" OnClick="btnReset_Click" />
                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
            <triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExcel" EventName="Click"/>
            </triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ofcourse above the html code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
```

The btnExcel is responding, but does not behave the same as outside the UpdatePanel.
The btnReset does respond and does what it should

aspx.cs:

```
 protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable Project1Table = (DataTable)ViewState["ProjectTable"];
        ExportToExcel(Project1Table, "Print2.xls");

    }
```

The problem probably has something to do with `ExportToExcel()` This function has to download a Excel file.

```
        private void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt, string FileName)
    {

            string filename = FileName + "";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
            dgGrid.DataBind();

            //Get the HTML for the control.
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            //Write the HTML back to the browser.
            //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
            this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
 }
```

As you can see I've tried adding AsyncPostBackTrigger (which is not in my toolbox?) but that did not solve the problem.

UpdatePanel visible=false because it will change when the user uses the correct username and password.

ChildrenAsTriggers is set to True 
BtnReset succesfully updates the lblInfo,
when I replace the `btnExcel` outside of the update panel, then it does what it should do.

Thanks for reading, good luck with solving :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button is not working with Update Panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665648/button-is-not-working-with-update-panel)

Comment: You can't download a file with an ajax request, you need to do a normal postback.

Comment: Ben How do I do that and still keep it within a UpdatePanel?
nsgocev, already checked that one, didn't gave me a solution